# MySQL first week of the year on WEEK function

Tags: mysql, date

I need some help. I want to get the week number of a specific date with the following system:
`The week containing January 1st is the first week of the year. The week begins on Sunday. Range 1-53.`
For example:

```
- Week 1 of 2015 begins on Sun 12/28/14 and ends on Sat 01/03/15.  
- Week 1 of 2016 begins on Sun 12/27/15 and ends on Sat 01/02/15.  
- Week 1 of 2017 begins on Sun 01/01/17 and ends on Sat 07/01/17.
```

I have read the `WEEK(date[,mode])` function documentation, but none of these 'modes' match with my requirements.
How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

You can probably get this by using the [DAYOFWEEK](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_dayofweek) function. It will return you the value of what the day is (1-7 where 1 is Sunday, etc). From there, you can determine when the week has started and when it will end.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I just edit my question: I need the week number of a especific date, to use in SELECT querys.

Answer (score 0):

You have the [WEEKOFYEAR](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_weekofyear) as well. Please go thru manual

Comment: Hi cjg, I checked that function (equivalent to WEEK(date,3)). For Jan/01/16, WEEKOFYEAR returns 53, and for Jan/01/17 WEKOFYEAR returns 52. Expect result in both cases is 1. `The week containing January 1st is the first week of the year`.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem, the function [YEARWEEK](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_yearweek) solved it for me

```
SELECT YEARWEEK("2016-01-01");
>> 201552
```